# Strange character conversion from HTML to JAVA

Tags: java, html, jsp, servlets, encoding

I'm sending through a form, some text inside a TEXTAREA and a INPUT with type="text".

In those boxes, when I write, for example "è", my destination Servlet receive "Ã¨".

I've tried adding `System.setProperty("file.encoding", "UTF-8");` but it's not working.

How can I solve this?

Comment: What Operating System is the target machine running on?

Comment: Try to put this attribute inside your form tag **accept-charset="ISO-8859-1"**

Comment: I'm running this both on Unix and Windows. Same problem

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your encoding on the server side is `Latin1`/`ISO-8859-1`/`ISO-8859-15` you have to change that.

You can do this by adding the following parameter to the `java` call.

```
java -Dfile.encoding=UTF-8
```

(see: [Setting the default Java character encoding?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/361975/setting-the-default-java-character-encoding) )

For Webservers (like `tomcat`) you will have to change that in the starting script.

Preferably you change the encoding on the whole machine to `UTF-8` if possible, so you wont get problems with files being `Latin1`

Answer (score 0):

Depending on your server configuration you may find that it is expecting or working in "ISO-8859-1".

You need to make sure that both client and server are using the same encoding.